# How to add a space for a DropDown Text which combines two columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

I have a asp.NET webform app.

There is a drop down on the form. I want the drop down text show combination of
2 fields in a table. coulmnA(age) and columnB(Name).

```
Here is my code:
  
                    DataSet d =GetDateSet();

                   

                    EnumerableRowCollection a = from t in d.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                                select new
                                                { txt = t[0] +"___ " + t[1] , val = t[0]};
                    ddlCustomer.DataSource = a;
                    ddlCustomer.DataBind();
                    ddlCustomer.Items.Insert(0, "Select Customer Here");
```

So far above is an easy task. Dropdown  will show something like below:

```
24___Joe
25___Biden
26__Donald
27___Trump
```

The problem is if I try to replace underlines with space it will be ignored. Any ideas how to fix this?

To be specific below code will not add space:

```
 EnumerableRowCollection a = from t in d.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                                select new
                                                { txt = t[0] +"    " + t[1] , val = t[0]  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, simple spaces in "markup" of course don't show.

So, say I have a drop down with hotel name.

but, I want 2 columns, and to include the city.

So, this markup:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server" 
            style="font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace;height:22px"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="MyHotelName">                
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Note how I am using a fixed space. So, you can now include "nbsp" in the text (non breaking spaces). You also have to force the server side code to ensure html output encoding.

So, say this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT ID, HotelName, City FROM tblHotelsA
              ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable rstData = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        // combine hotel name and city
        rstData.Columns.Add("MyHotelName");
        foreach (DataRow dr in rstData.Rows)
        {
            dr["MyHotelName"] = MyPad(dr["HotelName"], 20) + MyPad(dr["City"],15); 
        }
        cboHotels.DataSource = rstData;
        cboHotels.DataBind();
        cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Hotel", ""));

    }

    string MyPad(object MyColum,int NumChars)
    {
        string sResult = "";
        if (MyColum != null)
            sResult = ((string)MyColum);

        sResult = sResult.PadRight(NumChars).Substring(0, NumChars);
        sResult = sResult.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
        return Server.HtmlDecode(sResult);
    }
```

So, to save some "messy" code, I use a helper routine, and it "pads" out the string to the length I specify.

The result is now thus this:

[image]

so, to make this work, you need to use "nbsp".
(non breaking space).

You also want of course to use a fixed sized font - else the extra column will not line up with previous.

And by keeping the data value as the PK id, then above allows several columns, but the selected value remains the "data value" hidden column, which in this case is "id" (the hotel database PK row id).

Comment: "You also want of course to use a fixed sized font - else the extra column will not line up with previous.".   Yes data do not line up.  What do you mean by fixed font size here? Are you referring to font for entire page?

Comment: No, a fixed sized (mono-spaced) font for the drop down. Think of a command line prompt. Any text output results in the columns lined up - and lined up by using spaces. If you use a proportional font, then columns  will not line up between the 2 columns. So, yes, for the drop down, you want to specify a fixed type of font. In my example, I used the classic "courier" font. Try the example with the font removed, and see how it works - you see that columns don't line up).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, I have few of you solution and appreciate your help to the asp.net webform community who are finding hard to find reference or solutions related to webforms as we have very little support online now for webforms as majority moved to new  technologies even though there are tones of application still in asp.net webforms which need t be supported